# How to use the balance on your apple account in app store?

Tags: itunes-store

Recently I won a $10.00 gift card which I redeemed on Apple iTunes. So now when I open iTunes, to the left of my apple id, I see a $10.00 balance. My problem is that if I try to purchase an app, it asks me to enter my credit card information.

On the form where I am supposed to fill my credit card information, there's a link which says `to redeem your gift card click here`. Unfortunately, if I try to enter the code of the gift (mentioned at the beginning of this post) it says that the gift card has been already redeemed.

I guess that means that the amount of the gift card has already been credited to my account (as it shows to the left of my apple id on the iTunes program). The question is: how do I spend this balance?

Comment: Which region are you in / which iTunes store are you using? Initially, gift cards weren't redeemable for apps in the Canadian iTunes store, most likely for sales tax reasons. This may still be the case in your region. You should check the fine print on your gift card and see if it excludes apps. If that's the case, there is no way to purchase apps with that balance.

Comment: I am using it from Florida, USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just buy the app or the song or whatever and it will take from your balance first. I would check your settings to verify this, however.

Comment: For some reason, this does not seem to work for me...Purchases are taken from my visa card even though I have a gift card balance...

Answer (score -1):

One way to check your App Store account balance is to open iTunes, select the link to 'iTunes Store' on the pane on the left under 'Store'.

Click your email address in the top right (or click 'sign in' if required), login in and the value account balance, should be shown next to your email address.

Further details are available including a purchase history in the drop down, you should see the credit on the ''Account information' page under 'Apple ID balance'.

Once the balance is in place, you may still see a credit card prompt.  Some advice on the Apple support site suggests that you may need to complete a "purchase" of free app, and select "none" for payment type.

To try this - pick an app which is free, click to purchase. You should be prompted for payment details and an extra option should be available to select payment type: 'none'.

If you have balance from the redeemed gift card in place, then I think further app purchases may be possible without being prompted for card details.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question; he's not asking how to *check* his balance, he's asking how to *use* his $10 credit to purchase something, especially without a credit card.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice the reference to credit card prompt.